# assign decimal value to a string in java

Tags: java, if-statement, double, cannot-find-symbol

I am working on a GPA calculator where a user can enter in letter values such as A, B+, D- and so on but i am having trouble assigning the decimal values to the letter grade. I feel like i am not writing my code correctly. I am using an if-else statement to check the user input values then assigning a double to match it to the decimal value. I am also unsure how to incorporate the formula of the GPA calculation into my if-else statement.

the most common error i am getting is 
Error:(126, 24) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable gpa1
  location: class GPA

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GPA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is your grade in your first class?");
    String course1 = input1.next();


    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the grade in your second class?");
    String course2 = input2.next();


    Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the grade in your third class?");
    String course3 = input3.next();


    Scanner input4 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the grade in your fourth class?");
    String course4 = input4.next();


    System.out.println("Your grade in your first class was "+ course1);
    System.out.println("your grade in your second class was "+ course2);
    System.out.println("Your grade in your third class was "+ course3);
    System.out.println("Your grade in your fourth class was "+ course4);

        //double A = 4.00;
        //double Aminus = 3.70;
        //double Bplus = 3.33;
        //double B =  3.00;
        //double Bminus = 2.70;
        //double Cplus = 2.30;
        //double C = 2.00;
        //double Cminus = 1.70;
        //double Dplus = 1.30;
        //double D = 1.00;
        //double Dminus = 0.70;


    if (course1.equals("A")) {
        double grade1;
        grade1 = 4.00;
        double gpa1 = grade1;
    }else if (course1.equals("A-")) {
        double grade1;
        grade1 = 3.70;
        double gpa1 = grade1;
    }else if (course1.equals("B+")) {
        double grade1;
        grade1 = 3.33;
        double gpa1 = grade1;
    }else if (course1.equals("B")) {
        double grade1;
        grade1 = 3.00;
        double gpa1 = grade1;
    }else if (course1.equals("B-")) {
        double grade1;
        grade1 = 2.70;
        double gpa1 = grade1;
    }else if (course1.equals("C+")) {
        double grade1;
        grade1 = 2.30;
        double gpa1 = grade1;
    }else if (course1.equals("C")) {
        double grade1;
        grade1 = 2.00;
        double gpa1 = grade1;
    }else if (course1.equals("C-")) {
        double grade1;
        grade1 = 1.70;
        double gpa1 = grade1;
    }else if (course1.equals("D+")) {
        double grade1;
        grade1 = 1.30;
        double gpa1 = grade1;
    }else if (course1.equals("D")) {
        double grade1;
        grade1 = 1.00;
        double gpa1 = grade1;
    }else if (course1.equals("D-")) {
        double grade1;
        grade1 = 0.70;
        double gpa1 = grade1;
    }else if (course2.equals("A")) {
        double grade2;
        grade2 = 4.00;
    }else if (course2.equals("A-")) {
        double grade2;
        grade2 = 3.70;
    }else if (course2.equals("B+")) {
        double grade2;
        grade2 = 3.33;
    }else if (course2.equals("B")) {
        double grade2;
        grade2 = 3.00;
    }else if (course2.equals("B-")) {
        double grade2;
        grade2 = 2.70;
    }else if (course2.equals("C+")) {
        double grade2;
        grade2 = 2.30;
    }else if (course2.equals("C")) {
        double grade2;
        grade2 = 2.00;
    }else if (course2.equals("C-")) {
        double grade2;
        grade2 = 1.70;
    }else if (course2.equals("D+")) {
        double grade2;
        grade2 = 1.30;
    }else if (course2.equals("D")) {
        double grade2;
        grade2 = 1.00;
    }else if (course2.equals("D-")) {
        double grade2;
        grade2 = 0.70;
    }else {
        System.out.println("incorrect");

    System.out.println(gpa1);











    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`gpa1` is not in scope where you are trying to access it for printing.

Define it before your if/else statement, like so:

```
double gpa1 = 0.0;

if (course1.equals("A")) {
        double grade1;
        grade1 = 4.00;
        gpa1 = grade1;
} else if (course1.equals("A-")) {
        double grade1;
        grade1 = 3.70;
        gpa1 = grade1;
}
```